# Would it be weird or impractical for a princess who has a High Priestess title to have a family?

Tags: humans, culture, religion

My character is the King's only daughter in a patriarchal succession system. She's raised to become a High Priestess (the most important woman in the whole land), because only women of a male ruler's blood can serve as one. However, I'd like her to have a family in the future and I'm not sure if it will go along with her duty.

After her father's death, her oldest brother will become the king and have his own wife and kids (and, hopefully, future successor). Her other brothers will probably also start their families. What positions would her future children take in the palace? Isn't there a danger of having too many families at once?

Do you have any suggestions how to resolve this or how would that look in practice? I'll be grateful for all the ideas! Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Worldbuilding!  I'd recommend focusing on a single question - as it stands, you're opening this as a discussion topic, and that's not what this board is for.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  The SE Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  As written this question is too broad, too story-based, and [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).

Comment: Hey Royal Bee, as already mentioned, this question looks too broad and as some level of opinion based answers are allowed, your question relies heavily on that aspect. Try to reformulate it and be specific on one question per post.

Comment: Ancient Roman High Priests ([*Pontifices Maximi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontifex_maximus) had families. (The title Pontifex Maximus is still in use for the Pope, as the High Priest of Christendom, but Popes don't have families.) Still in ancient Rome, [Vestal Virgins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestal_Virgin) were allowed to marry once they had served for 30 years (which was around 36 years of age, the Romans considering that girls entered puberty at six). Among Christian apostolic Churches, the Orthodox, Anglican and *some* Catholic churches allow married priests.

Answer (score 4):

This is a fictional setting that you have created.  The social norms are also up to you.  The High Priestess could have, as part of her role, a Mother Goddess proxy status, where she is encouraged to have as many children as possible, from one or multiple fathers.  She could be the priestess of a Hearth Goddess, and be encouraged to show family standards after choosing (by whatever means) a suitable consort.

You're making up the rules.  There are no cultural limitations to address.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read up on the Vestal Virgins of ancient Rome, very important priestesses who served for a period of time and then were allowed to retire, get married, and possibly have children (assuming they weren't beyond childbearing age-- not impossible, considering they could be dedicated to the priestesshood as young as 6).  If, however, they violated their vow of celibacy before their term of service was over, they could be executed.

But as jdunlop said, this is a fictional world, and the social norms and expectations are up to you, as are the rules of royal succession to the throne, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Queen Elizabeth is the f. head of the Church of England, which makes her both the Queen and the High Priestess for her religion. She also has a family. So there you have a reference that is not only real, but also current.

Answer (score -1):

You can define whatever rules you want.

My mother and father both had full time jobs AND six kids, and they weren't rich. Your hero should be pretty rich, she can afford a full time servant to take care of her children when she has High Priestess duties to perform, even if that is every day. Most rich woman DO have servants to care for (and often teach) their children.

As for succession, just make it the rule that the male line takes precedence over the female line. Males in order of age are next in line to be King, the closer on the blood line of the King takes priority. So first the King's sons, oldest first, then sons of sons (by age) and then sons of daughters, and so on.

This doesn't have to match any existing royal system, it is just true for your world.

As for your hero's husband or whomever fathers her children, that is also up to you. If you want her to marry, let her get married. Or perhaps her father chooses a husband for her, as part of a political alliance with another kingdom.

Be a writer! Make it up!